# Use both OpenVPN & eth0 together

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, openvpn, routing

I connect to a VPN using openVPN. Now, after the connection is established, all my traffic goes through tun0.

My LAN gateway is 10.100.98.4...
So, for apps to use my direct internet connnection I did

> sudo route add default gw 10.100.98.4

But, I cant use tun0 now. I know this because

> curl --interface tun0 google.com

doesnt give me anything..
How do I go about **using both connections simultaneously**. How can I achieve that?

ROUTING TABLES:-

Without VPN running:-

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.100.98.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
default         10.100.98.4     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

With VPN:-

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.0.1       10.10.54.230    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.10.54.230    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
free-vpn.torvpn 10.100.98.4     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.100.98.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
default         10.10.54.230    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

After the route command-

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.0.1       10.10.54.230    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.10.54.230    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
free-vpn.torvpn 10.100.98.4     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.100.98.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
default         10.100.98.4     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         10.10.54.230    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

Comment: I am on ArchLinux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the default route, you're telling all your traffic to go back out of the gateway, so you're only going to get odd things happening.

If you have a particular network at the other end of your VPN that you need access to, you want to be adding specific routes to point at `tun0`. You can either do this manually by adding routes after the tunnel has come up, or better still change OpenVPN's `server.conf` file to 'push' the routes out to you when the tunnel comes up.

If you're wanting to do something a bit more complicated - say you're wanting to force all port 80 and 443 traffic down the VPN but make everything else go out of `eth0` - then you could use `iptables` to source NAT traffic matching particular rules to the IP address of `tun0` - something a bit like this:-

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.98.0/24 -d ! 10.10.98.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.54.230
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.98.0/24 -d ! 10.10.98.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.54.230
```

To make this persistent, as root, `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/iptables.rules`.

Good luck!

Comment: [shadyabhi@archlinux ~]$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.98.0/24 ! -d  10.10.98.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.100.98.4
[shadyabhi@archlinux ~]$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.98.0/24 ! -d  10.10.98.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 10.100.98.4
Actually, what I wanted was to do the opposite, send all http and https traffic through eth0 and rest through VPN.. After that I did $sudo iptables -L but no rules were displayed. Why so?

Comment: `iptables -L` will only show you the standard table - you want `iptables -t nat -L`. To do the opposite of what I said, you could do `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.98.0/24 ! -d 10.10.98.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 80,443 -j SNAT --to-source 10.100.98.4`

Comment: I did what you said but still my traffic from browser goes through VPN. I double checked, I did $iptables -L -t nat ;was showing the rule. What can be the issue?

Comment: Apologies - I made a typo in my previous comment - instead of `! --dports 80,443`, try `--dports 80,443` - i.e., without the `!` before `--dports`.